# Testing Windows 7 multitouch on a dev machine without multitouch?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, simulation, multi-touch

Is there a way to test the multitouch capability of an application using a non-multitouch enabled machine?  I'd like to simulate user input for zoom, scaling and rotating during runtime.

This is for a WPF application written in C#.

Comment: Take a look at this article [Developing Win 7 Multi-Touch Apps Without a Multi-Touch Screen](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2009/06/29/developing-win-7-multi-touch-apps-without-multi-touch-screen/)

Comment: How many fingers do you have Zed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using multiple mouse cursors:
http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/features/2006/dec06/12-14MultiPoint.mspx

Comment: With MultiPoint you still get mouse events, not touch events.